# Normal map calculation

Tags: calculus

The following peace of code calculate Normals based on tangent and binormal:

```
normal->x = (tangent.y * binormal.z) - (tangent.z * binormal.y);
normal->y = (tangent.z * binormal.x) - (tangent.x * binormal.z);
normal->z = (tangent.x * binormal.y) - (tangent.y * binormal.x);

// Calculate the length of the normal->
length = sqrt((normal->x * normal->x) + (normal->y * normal->y) + (normal->z * normal->z));

// Normalize the normal->
normal->x = normal->x / length;
normal->y = normal->y / length;
normal->z = normal->z / length;
```

Is it possible to calculate tangent and binormal from normal by changing this little piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.

The normal here is computed by taking the cross product of the tangent and binoromal, and normalizing the result. (The cross product of two vectors yields a vector that is orthogonal to the input vectors).

So you will always need two vectors to obtain the third one:

- You can compute the normal from the tangent and binormal
- You can compute the tangent from the normal and binormal
- You can compute the binormal from the tangent and normal

But from *one* vector alone, you can not compute *two* others.

---

Note that in some cases, there may be a solution: You sometimes have *one* vector, and just need *two* others that are orthogonal. In this case, you can "cheat" a little:

- Vector $v_0$ is given
- Pick a random vector $v_1$ that is orthogonal to $v_0$
- Compute $v_2 = v_0 \times v_1$

But I think that this will not yield "sensible" results when you want to compute a normal map.